# How to get Lots from stock location?

Tags: odoo, stock, odoo-13

I am creating a wizard on stock updation . But for updating a product, i am giving a many2one field where product.product can be added,a many2one field where stock location can be added and the after that, another many2one field to add lot.
When i select  a location from stock location, i want to set only the lots which comes under that specified product and in that location in the lot field.
How can i set my domain of lot id like this?

firstly, when i looked at the stock.production.lot model,it doesn't have any stock.location field connected with it. But, the lots which are created in stock.production.lot are connected to WH/Stock location. But i can create lots in other location through stock.quant.
I read the code, but couldn't find anything connecting stock.location and stock.production.lot.
When i am updating/creating a lot in stock.quant,the lots are shown on the basis of stock location onchange.